# Height 0 in components with Tabs

Tags: angular-material2

I want to make a component with dynamic material tabs

The component is meant to admin the tabs for certain pages and the idea is to re-use the component and centralice the logic to admin the pages

If I extract the md-tab-group to another component the height of the entire component is reduced to 0
Plunker with expected view:https://plnkr.co/edit/BilxU9 
Plunker with actual view: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bbb50t

The example doesn't have the service that I would use to admin the tabs from each page.

I've tried with dynamicHeight but it didn't work

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something that can't be done.

Thanks!

Example of finished code:

```
<page-tabed-card>
    <md-tab role="tab"  *ngFor="let tab of tabs | async; let i = index">
      <div role="tab" class="tab">
        <template md-tab-label>
          Content 1
          <b class="closer" (click)="close(i); $event.stopPropagation()">X</b>
        </template>
        <h1>Sushi restaurants</h1>
        <p>Mama Gao</p>
      </div>
    </md-tab>
</page-tabed-card>
```